# How to toggle ON/OFF tel: link on a webpage using CSS based on Width of the browser?

Tags: html, css, smartphone, tel

Before any admins decide to mark this question down or close it, I want to say that I have painstakingly done my due diligent part by scouring the INTERNET UP and DOWN and StackOverflow and still haven't found the solution that solves my issue.

I simply want to turn ON/OFF hyper link for my telephone number on a webpage or homepage based on the width of the browser using CSS and Media Query. If the webpage is opened on a desktop or the browser width is WIDER, then the **tel** link would be disabled just leaving the phone number as plain text. If the webpage is opened on a small device such as your smart phone or the width of the browser is very short like 400px, then the **tel** link should be enabled or active.

I came across this website where it posted an answer to do exactly what I want to do. I copied it word per word and paste it into my CSS and HTML page as follows.

**HTML**

```
<a class="moblink" href="tel:123456789" title="Call Me">123456789</a>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { /* W/E width you call "Mobile" */
            .moblink {
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
```

This code works. However, it works in an opposite direction. In other word, if you open my webpage on your desktop, the tel link is enabled or active allowing the user to click on the phone number itself. And if you open my webpage on your Smart Phone, the tel link is disabled or inactive. This is exactly what I want to do but in the other way or direction. Tel link active on a smart phone or smaller devices and inactive or disabled when my webpage is open on a desktop.

Any help or hints or clues will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want it the other way around, just change the `min-width: 500px` to `max-wdith: 500px` inside the media query. Also you might want to add `cursor: default;`

Comment: You are AWESOME, Jeremy. If you haven't noticed, I am new to CSS. :) it works like the way I want it to. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I placed the .moblink code within my other media query that was set for max-width. So, I simply copied this media query and pasted it in its own media query as-is and it works. :) Jeremy is still right. All I had to do was go from max to min or min to max. In my case, it was max-min... thanks again.